how to do multipage printing in datagridview
I am faced with the problem that I do not know how to transfer data that does not fit on one sheet. if necessary, here is my source code
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    
    float scale = 0.75f; 
    float width = e.MarginBounds.Width * scale;
    float height = e.MarginBounds.Height * scale;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height));

    
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(bitmap.Width * scale), (int)(bitmap.Height * scale)));

    
    e.HasMorePages = false; 
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; 
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

        
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


Try https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer

That's what you need, thank you!!
